# Neovim: How do I set normal mode and insert mode cursors to both blink and keep their separate styles?

Tags: neovim

I've been trying to find the right command to do this but it's a bit tricky any help?

By default no modes in neo vim blink, normal mode, visual mode and command mode are styled as solid block and insert mode is styled as a verticle line.

The goal is to keep these settings but allow normal mode and insert mode to blink as well.

I've tried ':set guicursor=n:blinkon100' but that somehow changes every mode to a blinking block when I was expecting only normal mode to change